# adobe JavaScript split string on period

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

How can I split a Javascript string in Adobe Acrobat on the period?

This is my first job working on an Adobe PDF and I'm working on a timesheet.

I have tried:

var monNTArr = monNT.split("\."); <-- does not work, is double backslash but only showing as single on SO

var monNTArr = monNT.split(/[..]/); <-- does not work

var monNTArr = monNT.split(/[.:]/); <-- does work

var monNTArr = monNT.split(/[.@]/); <-- does work

I seem to be able to split on any character except the period

Any help much appreciated

```
var monNT = this.getField("MonNT").value;
var monNTArr = monNT.split('.'); <--Throwing error and monMT value never shown
event.value = monNT;
```

Full code for Monday

```
//Mon
var monNT = this.getField("MonNT").value;
if(monNT.length == 0)
monNT = "0";
var monNTArr = monNT.split(".");
var monTotalMins = Number(monNTArr[0])*60 + Number(monNTArr[1])*60;
```

So if 1.50 is entered, I would do

1 x 60 = 60

.50 x 60 = 30

Added together = 90mins

=============ISSUE FIXED==========

After trying different options, fixed issue

Replace monNT.split('.') with monNT.toString().split(".")

Comment: `.split('.')` ?

Comment: Hi  CertainPerformance already tried that

Comment: What is the input and desired output? Can you give a concrete example or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different options, fixed issue

Replace monNT.split('.') with monNT.toString().split(".")